# Passing records from pl-sql to C# via ODP

Tags: c#, plsql, type-conversion

I'm working on a project which has a business logic on Pl-Sql and GUI in C#.

I have a record type in Pl-Sql representing `files` table as:

```
type file_record is record(
    id        number
   ,file_name varchar2(256));

type file_record_type is table of file_record index by pls_integer;
```

I want to get all the entries to table and pass them to C#.

Pl-Sql procedure is:

```
procedure get_all_file_names(p_files out file_record_type) is

v_counter number := 1;

begin

for c in (select id
                ,file_name
            from files) loop
  p_files(v_counter).id := c.id;
  p_files(v_counter).file_name := c.file_name;
  v_counter := v_counter + 1;
end loop;

end get_all_file_names;
```

And I'm calling this procedure via C# like this:

```
// get pmp entries from inside a specific file
    public DataSet getAllPmpFileNames(string commandText)
    {
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand();

        OracleParameter oracleParameter = new OracleParameter("p_files", OracleDbType.Object);
        oracleParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        oracleParameter.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
        oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(oracleParameter);

        oracleCommand.CommandText = commandText;
        oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        try
        {
            oracleCommand.Connection = m_Connection;
            OracleDataAdapter oracleDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(oracleCommand);
            oracleDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return dataSet;
    }
```

When I call this from C# I get the exception `OracleParameter.Size is invalid`

I can't give size before calling because I don't know. Should I first get the size and then call the procedure?

Or is there any other elegant way to reach multiple database elements from C#?

Answer (score 0):

Create a view instead of the stored procedure and employ an OracleDataReader to populate your DataSet.